# "curs_set()" failed to return the previous cursor state

Tags: c, ncurses, tty

According to the `curs_set` man page:

> The  `curs_set`  routine sets the cursor state to *invisible*, *normal*, or *very visible* for `visibility` equal to `0`, `1`, or `2` respectively.  If the terminal supports the
>          visibility requested, the previous cursor state is returned; otherwise, `ERR` is returned.

But the following simple program did not return the previous state:

```
[STEP 107] # cat curs_set.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curses.h>

int main()
{
    int ret;

    initscr();
    ret = curs_set(1);
    endwin();

    printf("curs_set() returned %d\n", ret);

    return 0;
}
[STEP 108] # gcc curs_set.c -lncurses
[STEP 109] # setterm -cursor off
[STEP 110] # ./a.out             <-- cursor invisible
curs_set() returned 1            <-- why not 0?
[STEP 111] # tput civis          <-- cursor visible
[STEP 112] # ./a.out             <-- cursor invisible
curs_set() returned 1            <-- why not 0?
[STEP 113] #                     <-- cursor visible
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: Looks like `initscr()` put the cursor in default terminal mode. Try different successive calls and you will see that it works.

Comment: Form man page: "A  program  should always call `endwin` before exiting or escaping from curses mode temporarily.  This routine
...
sets the cursor to normal visibility (see curs_set(3X))
..."

Comment: Also from man page: "There is no way for ncurses to determine the initial cursor state to restore that."

Comment: i did not notice that. wondering why the man page does not put this important info right under the `curs_set` section. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As reminded by [@vonaka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8208981/) in the comment, the man page also says (in a separate *NOTES* section):

> Both  `ncurses`  and  `SVr4`  will  call `curs_set()` in `endwin()` if `curs_set()` has been called to make the cursor other than *normal*, i.e., either *invisible* or *very visible*. **There is no way for *ncurses* to determine the initial cursor state to restore that.**